# Set keep-alive powershell command

Tags: migration, windows-server-2012, keep-alive

I am trying to enable the Keep-alive function on my windows server 2019 with PowerShell. It is a part of the preparation for migration to Azure. Does anybody know the PowerShell command to activate the keep-alive function?